# linq to sql get all objects and their container objects

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I am using NHibernate and Linq to NHibernate (mostly the same as Linq to SQL). What would I do to get the following:

I have class Garage, which has lots of Cars in it. I want to search Cars by year of manufacture, and also return the garage each car is in.

To get the cars, I do something like:

```
from item in session.Query<Car>()
where item.year == 2011
select item
```

The car class does not have garageID, the garage just has a collection of cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called eager loading, check out this article http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html